# How to loop through each table row and swap two rows using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there an inbuilt function or how do I create one on my own? I have tried what was done with swapping two cells with seemingly appropriate changes. But it didn't work.

This is what was written for swapping two cells. I want to swap rows and they're not necessarily consecutive. They can have multiple rows between them.

```
$('table tbody tr td:nth-child(3)').each(function() {
   let $td = $(this);
   $td.insertBefore($td.prev());
});
```

Comment: Do you want to swap cells or rows? Are you using jquery for that?

Comment: You could always select the `tr` instead and try for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate over rows this time:

```
$('table tbody tr:nth-child(3)').each(function() {
   let $tr = $(this);
   $tr.insertBefore($tr.prev());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The following will place the third row (index: 2) before the second (index: 1):

```js
// prepare a sample table:
$("table tbody").html([...new Array(5)].map((_,i)=>`<tr><td>${i}</td><td>some further text and a number ${i*i*i}</td></tr>`).join("\n"))

let $tr=$('table tbody tr:nth-child(3)')
$tr.insertBefore($tr.prev());
```

```css
td {padding:6px; border:1px grey solid}
tr:nth-child(odd) {background-color:#ddd}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table><tbody></tbody></table>
```

Unlike in the case for columns there is *no iteration* required here, as the row-exchange will happen only once!